# Firebase functions EventContext.auth is always null and EventContext.authType UNAUTHENTICATED

Tags: firebase, authentication, null, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Database and Firebase Auth for Unity and it worked very well until I updated my firebase tools from 3.19.3 to 4.0.1 and then 4.0.2 and made a deploy, even though I have no idea if that may be the problem, that's the only thing I changed. I can log in succesfully with a custom token and I can make changes to the database but whenever an event is triggered the auth property is missing. I also tested in the emulator with firebase:shell but still null.

I can reproduce the error with this simple test function.

```
exports.test = dbInstance.ref('/chats/{chatId}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    console.log("context " + JSON.stringify(context));
    console.log("auth " + context.auth);
    console.log("authType " + context.authType);
    console.log("uid " + context.auth.uid);
    console.log("token " + context.auth.token);
});
```

And this is my function.

```
exports.subscribeUserToChat = dbInstance.ref('/chats/{chatId}/createdTimestamp/')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    // Get the id of the chat and search in /members/{chatId} for the members.
    const chatId = context.params.chatId;
    console.log("context " + JSON.stringify(context));

    if (chatId.includes("-")) {
        // This is user to user chat.
        // Iterate the list of members and add the chat id in every member's chats property.
        return snapshot.ref.root.child("members").child(chatId).once('value')
            .then(function (snapshot) {
                let paths = {};
                snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                    paths["/users/" + child.key + "/chats/" + chatId] = true;
                });

                return snapshot.ref.root.update(paths);
            });
    } else {
        console.log("auth " + context.auth);
        console.log("authType " + context.authType);
        console.log("uid " + context.auth.uid);
        console.log("token " + context.auth.token);

        const factionId = context.auth.token.factionId;
        console.log("New chat created for faction id: " + factionId);
        // This is a faction chat.
        // Add the members and also the chat id in every member.
        return snapshot.ref.root.child("users").orderByChild("factionId").startAt(factionId).endAt(factionId)
            .once("value")
            .then(function (snapshot) {
                let paths = {};
                snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                    paths["/members/" + chatId + "/" + child.key] = child.val().name;
                    paths["/users/" + child.key + "/chats/" + chatId] = true;
                });

                return snapshot.ref.root.update(paths);
            });
    }
});
```

From within Unity I can see the logged user so it is not a problem with Firebase Auth I guess.

This is the context returned inside the function.

```
context {"eventId":"8fxAkOmHufupBKbN00IM2MyyAIE=","timestamp":"2018-08-04T00:19:32.531Z","eventType":"google.firebase.database.ref.create","resource":{"service":"firebaseio.com","name":"projects/_/instances/notmyrealdatabase-ptr/refs/chats/446/createdTimestamp"},"authType":"UNAUTHENTICATED","auth":null,"params":{"chatId":"446"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just returned to 3.19.3 and it worked again, so I don't know if it was the new version or the update process what caused the problem.